# Compound Link Destination Using Gatsby Link Via Props

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-component

I have a component called `Plan` that is using the Gatsby Link Component.  It looks something like this:

```
const Plan = props => (
  ...
  <Button>
    <Link to={props.goTo}>Learn More</Link>
  </Button>
  ...
)
```

This allows me to use the component as follows:  `<Plan goTo='events' />`, which will create the following URL:  `www.sitename.com/events`.

However, what I really want is for each URL to include `advertise` directory as follows:  `www.sitename.com/advertise/events`.  However, I don't want to have to include `advertise` in the `goTo` prop.

To get this result, I tried the following:

```
const Plan = props => (
  ...
  <Button>
    <Link to=`advertise/${props.goTo}`>Learn More</Link>
  </Button>
  ...
)
```

But this does not work.

So what I am wondering is how can I accomplish this.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Just to be clear -- this is how I use the component:

```
  <Plan goTo="events" />
  <PLan goTo="banner-ads" />
```

Currently, this leads to the following HTML (with class names stripped out):

```
<button><a href="/events">Learn More</a></button>
<button><a href="/banner-ads">Learn More</a></button>
```

What I want is to use the component in the **exact same way** (`<Plan goTo='events' />`), but have the HTML be slightly different:

```
<button><a href="/advertise/events">Learn More</a></button>
<button><a href="/advertise/banner-ads">Learn More</a></button>
```

[note the addition of `/advertise` at the beginning of the `href` attribute]

Comment: Could you add some detail to this report? What happens when you load that page, hover over the link, and click the link?

Comment: @JakeWorth Please see the new Update section that I added to my question.

Comment: The JSX and HTML you've shown don't line up. `advertise/${props.goTo}` should not be able to produce `/events`. Is it possible you have an unsaved file, a service worker, or some other kind of setup issue?

Comment: @JakeWorth  That JSX and HTML was a failed attempt to get the result I'm looking for.  I put it in the question simply to show what I'm trying to accomplish. 
 Right now, I'm using `<Link to={props.goTo}>Learn More</Link>`.  What I would like to how do I change that code so that `/advertise/` will automatically be added to the beginning of each URL.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. I think your solution would have worked with braces; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your backticks in braces:

```
<Link to={/`advertise/${props.goTo}`}>Learn More</Link>
```

The braces tell JSX that it needs to interpret the contents as JavaScript.

If you're adding `/advertise` to every path, consider adding that to your [Gatsby path prefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/).